# How to exclude route from history in vue-router?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, browser-history

I´ve implemented tabs with vue-router. When the user clicks back and forth within those tabs, but then likes to go to the previous page, he needs to press "back" multiple times to backplay each tab visit first.

**Is it possible to exclude routes from the history in vue-router like:**

```
let router = new VueRouter({
        mode: 'history',
        routes: [
             .
             .
             .
            {
                path: '/tabs/',
                name: 'tabs',
                component: TabPage
                children: [
                            {
                                path: 'tab1',
                                name: 'tab1',
                                component: Tab1Page,
                                excludeFromHistory: true
                            },
                            {
                                path: 'tab2',
                                name: 'tab2',
                                component: Tab2Page
                                excludeFromHistory: true
                            },

                ]
            }
       ]
   });
```

Comment: You want to have something like `/tabs/#tab1` and `/tabs/#tab2`, I guess: I don’t think so, but you can still have children components with IDs to get it working.

Comment: @FedericoMoretti I have that state already, however I want to exclude those routes from the history to skip them when the user navigates back in the browser

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Onclick on a tab:

> Instead of pushing a route to the route history, replace the
>   existing top of the route history.

```
<div @click="$router.replace('/tabs/tab1')"> Tab 1 </div>
```

In case you are using the router-link tag

```
<router-link to="/tabs/tab1" replace> Tab 1 </router-link>
```