# How to delete (the previous entry) from the Vue-router history?

Tags: vue-router

I would like to delete the previous history entry in Vue-Router, is that even possible?? The solution must work in Vue-Router 4.x, and ideally in 3.x as well.

The scenario that I'm implementing here is that a user does:

```
 pageA -> pageA:edit -> pageB
```

When hitting "back" at pageB, I want to go to pageA (regular, non-edit) instead.

I know that I could instead of a *push* to history of the page A:edit page, simply do a *replace*. However, it feels more natural that when hitting back in the A:edit page, you are returned to the regular non-edit page (there already is a check for changes in the beforeUpdate route guard, so that's covered).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to exclude route from history in vue-router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60684899/how-to-exclude-route-from-history-in-vue-router)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, the API mentions that it is impossible to clear (and I infer from that also to remove from) the session history. Full text:

"There is no way to clear the session history or to disable the back/forward navigation from unprivileged code. The closest available solution is the location.replace() method, which replaces the current item of the session history with the provided URL."

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/history

Unless someone knows a way, we'll have to accept it's impossible.

Comment: I am baffled that there is not a .pop() method myself. I ended up using only replace() and building a custom navigation array, which feels like re-inventing the wheel.